# WPF and C# ComboBox Next Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, focus

Im using WPF and C#. 
I have an application with an OnScreenKeyboard made with buttons.
When I press the tab button in the OnScreenKeyboard it does this:

```
if (IsEnterEnabled){
  CurrentTextBox.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
}
```

CurrentTextBox is a Control.

When a textbox is focused it works fine and move to the next focus, even if the next focus is a comboBox, but if the current focus is in an editable combo box it doesnt move to next focus element.

If the combo box is not editable, it works.

Comment: Did you check to see if that control can have focus? and is selectable / able to be tabbed to?

Comment: Yes, if I press the tab key in my real keyboard it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the ComboBox has a TextBox inside it which currently has focus,  telling ComboBox to move next will only move to the TextBox.   Instead, get the inner TextBox and move next on that:

```
        var s1 = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
        if (s1 is FrameworkElement)
        {
            ((FrameworkElement)s1).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [EnterKeyTraversal attached property](http://madprops.org/blog/enter-to-tab-as-an-attached-property/) code if you like. Add it to the top-level container on a WPF window and everything inside will treat enter as tab:

```
<ComboBox my:EnterKeyTraversal.IsEnabled="True">
...
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this on a PreviewKeyDown event of the ComboBox

```
private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            var comboBox = e.Source as ComboBox;
            var textBox = (comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox) as TextBox);
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Maybe this will help others.
This post helped a lot. [Set Cursor Focus into Editable Combobox in WPF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483650/set-cursor-focus-into-editable-combobox-in-wpf-c-sharp?rq=3)