# How to set the blinking cursor to WPF Editable ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, setfocus

In my WPF program I have a standard ComboBox (Editable). My desired behavior is that upon `FormLoad`, I would like the user to be able to type into the `ComboBox` and select from the list. (At `FormLoad` I've already populated it with some strings.) So I set `comboBox.Focus()`, and since I have `IsTextSearchEnabled="True"`, which is the default behavior, this works fine.

My problem is, when `comboBox.Focus()` is set, it does indeed focuses the control, but I do not get the blinking cursor inside it. This is what it looks like:

[image]

This in theory gets the job done, but I believe it's not very user-friendly. I would like the ComboBox to be focused, and also have the blinking cursor.

I get the blinking cursor when I click on the editable ComboBox, so I looked up what event gets fired when I do that. Turns out it's `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, so I tried programmatically firing this event (although this is something I usually try to avoid) to see if that will be an option. This is my code:

```
comboBox.RaiseEvent
(
    new MouseButtonEventArgs
    (
        Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 
        Environment.TickCount, 
        MouseButton.Left
    ) 
    { 
        RoutedEvent = PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent 
    }
);
```

I used a `Console.WriteLine()` to print a simple message to verify in Output Window if the event gets fired, and indeed it does. However, I still do NOT get the blinking cursor in my ComboBox.

Then I looked through SO, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31483650/302248) and the OP's edited fix seems to work. However this seems like quite a bit round-about way to get a seemingly simple task done, so I'm wondering if there's a rather straightforward or simpler way that I can achieve the desired result.

Comment: That link is the proper way to get it done. In WPF, the editable combo box is actually a composition of multiple elements, one being the dropdown list, and another being the textbox. If you want a blinking cursor, you need to find that textbox... and the posted answer on that link tells you how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Cursor Focus into Editable Combobox in WPF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483650/set-cursor-focus-into-editable-combobox-in-wpf-c-sharp)

Comment: @code4life So `PART_EditableTextBox` is the default name given by WPF to the TextBox in the ComboBox?

Comment: Oh and I already linked to that question from mine, and I do believe this question deserves to stay open because this fact was not very clear from that question itself.

Comment: yes, it is. If you have Expression Blend, you could actually "decompile" the combo box control, and take a closer look at the actual XAML that's used. I'd suggest delving into XAML as looking at control templates is something that you eventually need to master, if you plan to become good at WPF.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. And so I'm guessing the reason for `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent` to not work is also the same, probably that to take that approach I will again need to find the TextBox and fire event on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `Focus()` method once the window has loaded seems to work just fine for me:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        this.Loaded += (s,e) => comboBox.Focus();
     }
}
```

If it doesn't work for you, then please provide a reproducible sample of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: OK, so I figured out the problem. As I mentioned in the question, before loading occurs I populate my ComboBox with some strings, and at the end of that method I had a `comboBox.Focus()` as well. So when I have that AND another `Focus()` on load, it seems to focus alright but not get the cursor. When I removed that `Focus()` in the `Populate()` method, it works fine now! Thanks.